# Arangodb Graph, which one to use

Tags: graph, arangodb

I am new to Arangodb. I have confusion over which graph api to use. One graph I can see at `http://localhost:8529/` url. The official video talks about Gremlin (I have that installed too). Then there are talks about blueprint and rexster. I am confused.

What I want is to have a graph similar to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdXut_G7fLU#t=1250`

I have latest version of Arangodb installed. To achieve it do I have to :
1) Install blueprint
2) Install rexster
3) Install Gremlin

or blueprint and rexster is already installed? If not then which api is showing graph at the 8529 port url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you do not have to use Gremlin if you want to make use of ArangoDBs Graph features. This is just a driver if you would like to use Gremlin.

Therefore ArangoDB ships without Gremlin & co. if you want to use them you have to install them in addition.
If you want to go that way please follow the instructions of the README of https://github.com/triAGENS/blueprints-arangodb-graph
(To answer your comment right away the jar-file is obtained after executing `mvn clean install` in the blueprints driver repository.)

If you simply want to use the graph features (maybe even in an other language then Java) please checkout ArangoDBs drivers https://www.arangodb.com/drivers to pick the driver for your language.
Most of them have a running implementation of our old graph module https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/44c2063662bcdc316478048781f80457fa22b0a6/Documentation/Books/Users/Blueprint-Graphs/README.mdpp and some of them already support the new (recommended) graph module https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/graphs/general-graphs/.

If you do not want to build an application straight away you can also use the WebInterface (visually) to create an example graph using the graphs tab (simply create a new graph, give it some collections (they do not have to exist yet)). Next you can click on the graph and be forwarded to the visual editor where you can create your graph using the toolbar an the left hand side. If you want to play around more shell-style i would suggest you use the `arangosh` shipped with ArangoDB. There you can copy & paste the examples from the documentation links above. To get a feeling how things work in ArangoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Cloned the git repository `https://github.com/triAGENS/blueprints-arangodb-graph` at my local from eclipse and then right click on the project and click on Install. It creates the necessary jar.

Comment: Yes if you are using an IDE they mostly have maven support build in.